# have problem in my flutter application , worked fine till yesterday but today i am getting build error

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, facebook-login

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Read timed out

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

this is the error I get while running the application

i tried adding mavenCentral() in my build.gradle file as some of the suggestions out there but it didn't work for me. I also tried

```
 implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'
```

but it's still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hi in your build.gradle you should not add implementation
> "com.facebook.android:facebook-login:15.0.2" because this plugin
> already define that dependency for you.

ref: [https://github.com/darwin-morocho/flutter-facebook-auth/issues/301#issuecomment-1296944186](https://github.com/darwin-morocho/flutter-facebook-auth/issues/301)

Remove this line from build.gradle:  `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'`

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem now and I found that there was an outage with a jcenter :

https://status.gradle.com/

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: I followed this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/74261013/7914759 
I have removed jcenter from my build.gradle and built the app without an internet connection at first, than rebuilt with it. It worked for me.

Comment: This can't work with CI/CD.

Answer (score 0):

as a temperary measure,

I suggest using this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Jcenter mirror
        maven { url "https://maven.aliyun.com/repository/jcenter" }
        // other repo
    }
}
```

or other mirror

**--- Update ---**

In other way

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        all { ArtifactRepository repo ->
            if (repo instanceof MavenArtifactRepository) {
                if (repo.url.toString().startsWith('https://jcenter.bintray.com/')) {
                    remove repo
                    add(mavenCentral())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code changes to mavenCentral url if jcenter url exists.

Comment: didn't work .. any other ways to solve it ?

Comment: Are you remove Jcenter() line?

Comment: i did tried the both cases using Jcenter() once  and removing it the next time .. both didn't work out

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: update post. please check it

Answer (score 0):

From Hours of research if finally found that. this is an issue due to jcenter is down.
According to [official documentation](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/) the jcenter depricated and `Bintray/JCenter users should start migrating to a new hosting solution.`
the solution for this is to remove jcenter from `build file` and replace it with

```
mavenCentral() // <- add it
```

for react-native users `jcenter()` may be exists in some depedency that you installed recently. to check for jcenter open your project in `android-studio` to check all `build.gradle` files easliy.

Another solution for this is that disconnect your system from internet and build your project. after you lanuc your project reconnect your system to internet.