# JCentre may be down permanently. What are our options?

Tags: android, react-native, jcenter

I have been trying to build a react native app since the early hour of today but was getting the follwing errors:

```
> Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
> Read timed out
```

After checking out https://jcenter.bintray.com, I found out it was down. Can anyone point me to the right option to resolve this issue? Is there any alternative since they said the site may not come back up?

Comment: `jcenter()` was deprecated for a long time. Like, years, maybe 2 or 3 years even. For main libraries, there will be versions published under maven central, or their own repositories, depending on the library. You should check their respective documentations to find whether they have publications elsewhere.

Comment: For example I've found the react-native library integration under here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74260926/could-not-head-https-jcenter-bintray-com-com-facebook-react-react-native-mave

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is already [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74261013/11037116).

As mentioned in [this source:](https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/)

> No more submissions will be accepted to JCenter since March 31st, 2021.

So you should migrate all of your repositories to the alternative hosts such as **mavenCentral**.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the answered issue](https://github.com/Shopify/react-native-skia/issues/1039#issuecomment-1297127382) on Github, a temporary solution could be like the following:

```
android/build.gradle
```

```
all { ArtifactRepository repo ->
  if(repo instanceof MavenArtifactRepository){
    def url = repo.url.toString()
    if (url.startsWith('https://jcenter.bintray.com/')) {
      remove repo
    }
  }
}
```

if the issue came form `node_modules` you can use `patck-package` to keep the changes on production environment.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/74265617/772091 , dependencies can come with their own `jcenter()` repository. If you can wait for every dependency to be updated, you can force remove those repositories, using your `android/app/build.gradle` file :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        all { ArtifactRepository repo ->
            if (repo instanceof MavenArtifactRepository) {
                def url = repo.url.toString()
                if (url.startsWith('https://jcenter.bintray.com/')) {
                    remove repo
                }
            }
        }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference links, [FIXED] Android build failures : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).